# Can't Update My Modul in Odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I wanna ask about Update my Modul in Odoo.

I have created "modul" in folder Download.

next step, i have moved "modul" to addons via terminal

> mv /home/downloads/ modul /opt/odoo/addons/

but, while update list module in odoo, my modul can't read.

i have been restart server, changed permission to Odoo.Odoo same with all modul in Odoo.

Thank You

Comment: Did you create openerp file? In openerp file, if you set application: False, you have to remove the Apps filter in the search box. Also you should check it your module is installable (set installable: True in openerp)

Comment: Check if odoo can access `modul` folder (permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check this following in `__openerp__.py`

```
'installable': True,
'application': True,
```

> Then give rights to your module by

```
chomd 777 "path of your module"
```

> Then also check that on the time when you are searching your module
>   check App is removed or not.As shown in below Image.

[image: App-removed-in-search]